# Помогите с кодом на с++(массив)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int
main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
int* array = new int[n];
cout << "input: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (array[i] = array[i + 1]) 
    { 
        delete[] array[i]; // E0852 выражение должно представлять собой указатель на полный тип объекта 
    }
}
}
```

Задание состоит в том, чтобы убрать одинаковые элементы массива. Не знаю как это реализовать(

Comment: для чего у вас ```#include <conio.h> , #include <vector>, #include <algorithm>```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убрать элементы массива - это, по сути, из массива в `n` элементов получить массив, в котором будет `m` элементов, отвечающих вашему критерию.

Т.е. примерно

```
sort(array,array+n);
int m = unique(array,array+n) - array;
```

Полностью:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* array = new int[n];
    cout << "input: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    sort(array,array+n);
    int m = unique(array,array+n) - array;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

С `vector` было бы в определенном смысле проще...

Comment: Тогда уж множества Вам в помощь https://proginfo.ru/set/

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak `set` ни разу не аналог массива, в то время как `vector` - вполне...

Comment: а собственно причем тут аналог не аналог,?!?!?! предложенное Вами решение не самое простое и не изящное, используя set  на этапе ввода уже отсеет все дубликаты и вывод покажет только уникальные значения. Порядок ввода значений после сортировки Вы и так потеряете.

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak При том, что в вопросе не говорится о том, что надо просто получить из потока данные и выбросить дубли - для этого применяются иные способы. Вопрос обычно усечен (*"минимальный код, демонстрирующий проблему"*), так что я не могу утверждать, что между вводом в массив и удалением дублей не выполняются иные действия, где нужен именно этот массив. Или что дубли не появляются в массиве именно в результате этих действий...

Answer (score 0):

И условие на равенство это  a[i]==a[i+1].
Для формирования коллекции уникальных значений можно или спец коллекцйию использовать типа множества, но у Вас видимо задачка на массивы, так и формируйте новый массив уникальных значений, используя два вложенных цикла, первый по исходному массиву, просмотреть все элементы, а вложенный цикл для занесения в массив уникальных значений , если там нет ни одного совпадения

```
int k=0;//количество найденных уникальных элементов,длинна массива b
for(int i=0...){bool flag_unique = true;
for(int j=0...)
if(a[i]==b[j]) {flag_unique=false;break;}
if(flag_unique) b[k++]=a[i];}
```